# Iterating through Firebase database with a while loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a table of review questions, Every time the user gets a question wrong a question gets added to this table. When trying use this function I iterate through the table to display each question.

like this:

```
databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Review Questions").child(userid).child("Pollution");

databaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       final  Iterator<DataSnapshot> questions = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (questions.hasNext()) {
            final DataSnapshot question = questions.next();
            t1_question.setText(question.child("question").getValue().toString());
            b1.setText(question.child("answer1").getValue().toString());
            b2.setText(question.child("answer2").getValue().toString());
            b3.setText(question.child("answer3").getValue().toString());
            b4.setText(question.child("answerCorrect").getValue().toString());



            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            incorrect++;
                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                            description.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            description.setText(question.child("description").getValue().toString());


                        }
```

I have four buttons I have just shown one button as an example. For some reason it is displaying the last question from the table of Review questions. SO it isn't iterating through them as the last questions doesn't have a next value.

I also have a next button, this should be used to move onto the next question, written like this:

```
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    description.setText("");
                    description.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    total = total + 1;

                    UpdateQuestion();
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
```

Database tree shown with the question that it prints circled:

[image: Database tree]

Is there something wrong with my code?

I can't seem to see why it does this,

Is it possible it is reading the other questions although I cant see this as there is nothing to pause the while loop? If so how would I do this

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the labels of the same buttons in every iteration of the loop:

```
b1.setText(...)
```

So at the end of the loop, `b1` ends up with the `answer1` value of the last question.

You'll need to have/generate UI elements (labels, text views, buttons) for each question. The typical way to do that is by using a `RecyclerView`. I recommend reading up on [populating recyclerview from firebase](https://www.google.com/search?q=populating+recyclerview+from+firebase) as that topic is quite broad.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I have the questions all on one view?. My plan was to have the format of each time the user answers a q and clicks next the next question comes up, do you think this isnt possible with a while loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered the question yourself. The problem is that you are setting the OnClickListener for your buttons in the while loop without waiting for the question to be answered. Every button can have 1 OnClickListener, and you are overwriting this value with every loop iteration even though the question hasn't been answered yet. You will notice that when you set a debug marker at any line inside the loop and then run debug.

I would not use a while loop in this case, but introduce a counter/index variable like  int questionIndex and increase that counter everytime a question has been answered. The next question can be shown according  to this index and the win condition would be (index == questions.length -1) or something similar.

Comment: I tried changing my code to this:

 ` 
final Iterator<DataSnapshot> questions = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();


                            final DataSnapshot question = questions.next();

                            if (total > dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {


                                description.setText("Completed");
                                details();


                            } else { `

Although now it is stuck on the first question and doesn't itterate through.